# DVD utility SW that maps sector to a Title/Chpt/Time mark

Tags: optical-media, utility

I'm looking for a DVD utility SW that can map a sector on the DVD to the DVD's Title-Chapter and/or time.

I'm not looking for a DVD-testing SW (like VSO Inspector) or a DVD-cloning SW.

Instead, what I'm looking for is software that lets me enter a sector number. Then the SW will show the Title #, Chpt #, and the time point where that sector is.  Of course, the DVD would be in the DVD drive on the PC.

For example, if I enter sector **#2262640**, the DVD utility SW would return something like `Title 5, Chpt 2, 0:22:14`.

Looking for something that runs on Windows 7 or later but if need be, the SW can be Centos or Ubuntu v16+.

Is there such a type of DVD utility SW that I can either download or buy?

(PS: I can answer the "why" question in the comments section later)

Comment: The why would be better as part of the question.

Comment: Answering the why question: I bought a used Sex and the City DVD set from a buyer on EBay.  One of the disks was bad; VSO Inspector showed media errors on one of the DVDs.  I contacted the seller and he claimed that all the DVDs were good because he tested them on his DVD player.  I sent him the VSO logs but he wouldn't look at them.  I had to view the DVD minute by minute to find the defective area.  If I had this SW, it would tell me exactly where the defect occurred rather than having to watch the DVD minute by minute.  That's why I want a DVD utility software like this.

Comment: A wildly different solution.  Download the dvd and make a copy.  Since you have the original, it's technically not piracy.

Comment: @RohitGupta, I can't download all the titles, such as Sex and the City show.  I would rather have a DVD utility SW that does what I am looking for so I don't have to go thru the DVD minute by minute to find where the defect is.